# KOTLIN - KTOR - Impossible to add a response type to a get request in KTOR

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to user KTOR in KOTLIN. The tutorial shows that we can specify a response type after a get request :

In the tuto,  i have seen this syntaxe is correct :

```
        val post: HttpResponse =
            client.get<String> { url("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") }
```

But when i try to add the response type "String" (or other type), i have a error :

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
HttpClient.get(Url, HttpRequestBuilder.() → Unit = ...) defined in io.ktor.client.request
HttpClient.get(URL, HttpRequestBuilder.() → Unit = ...) defined in io.ktor.client.request
HttpClient.get(String, HttpRequestBuilder.() → Unit = ...) defined in io.ktor.client.request.

Here my client

```
    val client = HttpClient(Android)
    {
        install(ContentNegotiation)
        {
            json()
        }
    }
```

here are my dependancies

```
var ktor_version = "2.3.8"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version"
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")
```

Someone has a idea ?

I verify all my code with many tutorial and i can't see where my problem is.

Comment: Most likely, the tutorial is for Ktor 1.*, but you use version `2.3.8` where the API of receiving the request body has been changed. You can find more information in the official documentation (https://ktor.io/docs/response.html#body).

Comment: Thanks, it's seems in 2.3.8 we can't specify a response type but directly use the json format as result

Comment: You can do it by using the `body` method.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [Making requests](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html) there are different ways to build a request

Try to do this way

`client.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")`

Comment: Yes, this syntaxe works, but the question is : "how can add a response type ? "

Comment: you can set contentType in headers, you wrote install(ContentNegotiation) { json() }, that means by default your httpresponse will be parsed to json

Comment: try this 
val response: HttpResponse = client.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts") {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody(Post(...))
}